# Compare 2 CSV files and output one file of matches, one file of non-matches

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have 2 CSV files (that are `|` delimited) I am trying to compare in a bash script.  File A has 5 columns; File B has 1 column.  I do not have any headers currently, was going to add them in later.  Column 5 in File 1 contains some entries that match Column 1 in File 2.  I would like to end up with 2 new files:  File C that has Columns 1-5 from File A where File A Column 1 and File B Column 1 match; File D that has Columns 1-5 from File A where File A Column 1 and File B Column 1 do not match.

Sample Text from File A:

```
 CT240021313|2024-02-04 00:00:02|CT|1.2.345.6
 AB123|2024-02-01 11:22:33|MR|7.8.98.102
 PDQ987|2024-02-04 8:50:11|XR|1.23.45.6
 PA7531|2024-02-03 9:34:52|CT|6.3.489
```

Sample Text from File B:

```
1.2.345.6
6.3.489
```

Expected output File C:

```
CT240021313|2024-02-04 00:00:02|CT|1.2.345.6
PA7531|2024-02-03 9:34:52|CT|6.3.489
```

Expected output File D:

```
 AB123|2024-02-01 11:22:33|MR|7.8.98.102
 PDQ987|2024-02-04 8:50:11|XR|1.23.45.6
```

I've tried several variations on awk, with little to no success even finding any matches.  Yet I can export the files and import into Excel, and highlight the matching values from File A Column 5 and File B Column 1 and it finds many matches.  What I have currently, which returns basically every line in File A:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next !($0 in a)' file_a.csv file_b.csv  > file_c.csv
```

Comment: comm doesn't seem to work because the data needs to be sorted, but the files will not match line for line.  cut I can't figure out how to "define" File B Column 1 as a character.

Comment: Using: awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$0;next} A[$5]' file_a.csv file_b.csv > file_c.csv
Returns the data from File B Column 1 that matches File A Column 5.  Now I just need it reversed, to where it outputs the lines from File A that match.  But when I switch the file names around and the $1->$5 variables, it returns an empty csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR{b[$0];next} ($4 in b){print>"C";next} {print>"D"}' B A
```

You were already on a good track, but had the order mixed up.
Here, we specify the input files the other way around. First, we read `B` into memory, and then we partition `A` based on the values we saw in `B` before.

Comment: `($4 in b){print>"C";next} {print>"D"}` = `{print > ($4 in b ? "C" : "D")}`

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you. I thought something similar after posting this, but didn't want to test and edit the answer again :)